# provide custom command line options for kubectl for kubernetes operator

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

I have one kubernetes operator (ex: `kubectl get oracle_ctrl`). Now I want to provide custom arguments for the kubectl command.
ex: `kubectl apply oracle_ctrl --auto-discover=true --name=vcn1`

I can write one more controller to do the same job. But I don't want to write one more controller and make use of existing controller.

Is it possible to use operator-sdk to provide custom args to kubectl?

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't possible.

[kubernetes/kubectl#914](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/914) has a little bit further discussion of this, but its essential description is "we should start the proposal and design process to eventually write something better than `kubectl create` to support it".  Your CRD can [define additional columns to be shown in `kubectl get`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#additional-printer-columns) but this is really the only `kubectl`-related extension point.  You could potentially create a [kubectl plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubectl/kubectl-plugins/) or another CLI tool that does what you need.

Rather than using the `kubectl` imperative tools, it's often a better practice to directly write YAML artifacts and commit them to source control.  You can parameterize these using tools like Helm or Kustomize.  If `kubectl apply -f` or `helm install` is your primary way of loading things into the cluster, then you don't need custom CLI options to make this work.